# MySQL Stored Procedure and Identifiers

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I am learning to write MySQL stored procedures and I have encountered some difficulties. Here I have two stored procedures:

**First stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 (IN `username` TEXT, OUT `user_id` INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE rowcount INT;

    SELECT count(`User ID`) INTO rowcount FROM user WHERE `Username`=username;

    SET user_id = rowcount;
END|
```

**Second stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp2 (IN `doc_id` INT, IN `content` LONGTEXT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE doc SET `Content`=content WHERE `Doc ID`=doc_id;
END|
```

(Delimiter is `|`.)

**Question:**

I observe that the result of the first stored procedure is the same as calling `` SELECT count(`User ID`) FROM user; ``. However, the second stored procedure does its job and gets the content updated with the new content.

So why does the first stored procedure treat `` `Username` `` and `username` as equal identifiers but the second stored procedure treats `` `Content` `` and `content` as different identifiers? The two identifiers in both cases are the same except the capitalization of the first letter.

Comment: @RyanVincent If I change the IN parameter to `doc id` and then change the ``WHERE`` clause to `Doc ID`=`doc id`, then every record is updated, just like the ``WHERE`` clause in the 1st SP. I just read the official MySQL documentation about the scope of local variables and it just answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out after reading the official MySQL documentation about [the scope of local variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html).

It states that:

> A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a SELECT ... INTO statement, **contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable**.